# Где реализовать очистку полей?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

Как правильно очистить поля(TextBox) форме. Пробую использовать паттерн MVP есть форма фильтра и в ней много полей. Рядом с полем есть кнопка очистки поля. Где прописать логику очистки свойства связанного с полем? Если делать через Presenter то это будет куча событий, это нормально?

Comment: Если действие связано только с состоянием контролов во View и никак не связано с данными из модели, например очистка текстбокса, выделение всего текста в текстбоксе при получении им фокуса, и проч., то это нужно делать в самой View, т.е в кодбихайнд.